# two UIView Animation on the same image

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, methods, uiimageview

Well I would like to have two UIView animation on a same image in the same method like this :

```
-(void)likeThis{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        image.alpha=0;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(5,5);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

But there is only one of these UIView Animation who work.I don't know why.I think there is another way to put two animation for the same image but I don't know how. sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put them in the same animation block:

```
-(void)likeThis
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    image.alpha=0;
    image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(image.transform,5,5);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Note that CGAffineTransformScale takes three arguments:

CGAffineTransformScale(image.transform, 5.0, 5.0)

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946-CH1g-F16985

Or you could use CGAffineTransformMakeScale: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Answer (score 2):

Do you want them to happen simultaneously, or one after the other?  If the former just include them both between a single set of  beginAnimations..commitAnimations calls